# C++ read popen error output into string

Tags: c++

I'm opening a process via the posix `popen()` function. E.g. git push, mkdir x, etc.

I can read the output from these commands easily by storing it into a buffer like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

FILE *in;
char buff[512];

if(!(in = popen("mkdir x", "r"))){
    return 1;
}

// fgets stores the output into buff
while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL){
    cout << buff;
}
pclose(in);

return 0;

}
```

But then if there is an error with the process, e.g. mkdir fails, then I want to read the error into a string or character buffer.

However, with the code above, if it fails, the error isn't stored in the buffer. I think it is because the error is redirected to standard error instead of standard input.

How do I modify the code above to get the error message returned by bash/the process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify redirection in the `popen` method call:

```
popen("mkdir x 2>&1", "r")
```

You'd then be able to read the error message from the buffer.

Comment: Would this still capture the normal output (if there are no errors) into the buffer?

Comment: @DramaticStackoverflowPirate yes. `2>&1` means write stderr (2) to stdout (1) but it doesn't drop stdout, it effectively combines combines the two.